# Baixar um torrent com python

Tags: python, bittorrent

Como baixar arquivos torrent com Python de um modo simples?
Existe uma biblioteca no python que faça isso?

Answer (score 2):

Implementar P2P no Python não será simples uma vez que não há bibliotecas de network que abstraem isso completamente mas encontrei algumas referências que podem guiá-lo:

http://khashmir.sourceforge.net/

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyp2p

Existiam outras libs tabém como kenosis e Cspace mas não encontrei as páginas.

Comment: Obg isso será de grande ajuda :)